# Sending a zip file as attachement to a JSON post request in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on a iphone app that connects to a json based web service. In one of the requests, I need to send a zip file along with JSON data. How do I achieve this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Consider encoding the contents of the ZIP file as a Base64 field. You can also send down your JSON response and include a link to get the ZIP file.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ASIHTTPRequest` library would make this quite easy. They have an example on their [documentation page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) that could be easily adapted from an image file to a zip file.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addData:zipData withFileName:@"mydata.zip" andContentType:@" application/zip" forKey:@"zipfile"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cant use ASIHTTP lib. My app is 5.0 with ARC. Another thing is ASI is no more being developed. Suggest something with native iOS.

Comment: You can use ASIHTTP with ARC. Just add the -fno-objc-arc to the .m files on compile sources of the build phases tab of your target.